# how do I go from the back office to see the front end changes of my store? no link to view store front?

Tags: frontend, store-view

I'm a total newbie and can't see how to move out of the back office to see the front end of my store?
I expected a link (as in prestashop - view my store) but its not there with Magento?

Help anyone
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Magento 1 does not have this link. (Magento 2 has one though).
But you can view your frontend by taking any admin url and remove the the end. Everything starting with `/admin/...`.  You will get the frontend url.

So if your admin url looks like `http://example.com/index.php/admin/somethng....` the frontend url is `http://example.com/index.php/`.
Note: `index.php` can be removed also.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the link modifying or, better, overriding the file:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/header.phtml
```

and adding the code:

```
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl();?>"><?php echo $this->__('View store')?></a>
```

the best position is at the end of `<p class=super>` block